# Word to describe a group of businesses selling the same product in the same location

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for *a group of businesses all selling the same product in the same location*? For example, many cities have streets lined only by jewelry stores, clothing shops, or some other specific type of merchant.

I'm looking for a way to describe that situation, something similar to the word **hub** .

Comment: I don't know if it works for outside vendors, but a word referring to multiple vendors in one shop is **colocated**. (one l; two l's is a different word) Also **market** might be applicable, as in *farmers' market*, *flea market*.

Comment: can also be known as a ***district*** if it’s big enough.  See [New York’s Garment District](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garment_District,_Manhattan) for example.

Comment: hub is for transportation, trucks, airports and buses, for example.

Comment: In Philadelphia, the term is "row": The most touristy and externally known is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewelers%27_Row,_Philadelphia but there is also a Fabric Row and a Cooks Row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often in a city an area where the same businesses trade is known as a **quarter** - as in the Jewellery Quarter

Answer (score 2):

It's a form of clustering called:

> #### Retail Clustering
>
> - The grouping of stores based on common store and demographic characteristics.

Relevant links and articles:

http://www.parkeravery.com/pov_Retail_Clustering_Methods.html

http://www.kurtsalmon.com/en-us/Retail/vertical-insight/319/The-Five-Deadly-Sins-of-Clustering

http://risnews.edgl.com/retail-news/Advanced-Planning-and-Optimization-Part-3--Store-Clustering38904

Comment: That is a business  term, not one to describe the geography, as it were.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consortium; thus the word consortium could be an option.